# Load controller from module hmvc codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have my normal mvc directory's at codeigniter like:

- Models
- Views
- Controllers

But I use the wiredesigz "plugin" for hmvc support, so I have this structure:

- Models
- Views
- Controllers
- Modules

  - TestModule

    - Models
    - Views
    - Controllers

I have this code at my root controllers folder:

```
class Core_Test_Controller extends MX_controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getText() {
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

And this at the /Modules/TestModule/Controllers:

```
   class InsertController extends MX_Controller
    {
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

       function testIt{
           $coreTestController = new $this->Core_Test_Controller();
           $text = $coreTestController->getText();
           print_r($text);
        }
    }
```

But I get the error that class Core_Test_Controller is not found. Why can't I acces that controller from another controller? Is this even possible?

Fixed it:

Modules::load('../Core_Test_Controller/')->getText();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off lower case for folder names. Only first letter must be upper case for controller names and models etc UCFIRST as explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming HMVC wont pick up CI_Controllers controllers only MX_Controllers

```
class Core_test_controller extends MX_controller {...}

class Insertcontroller extends MX_Controller {...}
```

As said here

```
<?php
/** module and controller names are different, you must include the method name also, including 'index' **/
modules::run('module/controller/method', $params, $...);

/** module and controller names are the same but the method is not 'index' **/
modules::run('module/method', $params, $...);

/** module and controller names are the same and the method is 'index' **/
modules::run('module', $params, $...);

/** Parameters are optional, You may pass any number of parameters. **/
```

Comment: So I don't need the instantiate the class Core_Test_Controller?

Comment: Modules run loads the controllers have look through here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: @da1lbi3  This is a very old tutorial not much difference just the file naming and class naming https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ

Comment: I have this: $output = modules::run('/controllers/Core_Test_Controller/testIt');, but it says nothing. No error, Nothing.

Comment: That has to be in a modules folder does not pick up any from main controllers you will need to place that controller in a modules controllers folder

Comment: And follow the file and class nameing method http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming